# clusterer = KMeansClusterer(10, euclidean_distance) NameError: name 'euclidean_distance' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on python using `nltk` and `numpy` packages to write my code for clustering documents by k-means. I've imported euclidean_distance from the package `nltk` as below:

```
from nltk.cluster import KMeansClusterer, euclidean_distance
```

Still it's showing me error while using it for clustering. Throwing below error

```
clusterer = KMeansClusterer(10, euclidean_distance)
NameError: name 'euclidean_distance' is not defined
```

If someone please could help me here.

Comment: Why don't you use Scikit-learn ? You will get a lot more of documentation

Comment: When I'm trying to import Euclidean_distance from shell, it's giving no error:
 from nltk.cluster import euclidean_distance

Comment: Sickit-learn seems to be working properly only when one download and implement Anaconda.

Comment: Not so sure about that ! try pip install

Comment: With pip install, it is giving following errors :
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .nmf import NMF, ProjectedGradientNMF
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\nmf.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import nnls
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    from ._minimize import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 26, in <module>

Comment: Few more :
from ._trustregion_dogleg import _minimize_dogleg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_dogleg.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scipy.linalg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 145, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.